# Powerbuilder tabpage visible (shown)?

Tags: tabs, powerbuilder, tabpage

How do you tell if a Powerbuilder tabpage is visible or not?  The VISIBLE property is TRUE anyway regardless of whether the tabpage is selected or not.  SelectionChanged() is called at initialization time and not when the tabpage is shown.

Answer (score 1):

To know what is the currently displayed tab page, you can check the `tab.SelectedTab` property: it will return the current index.

You can also set the `tab.SelectedTab` property to change the page to display as you can call `tab.SelectTab()`

Comment: Visible and Selected are two different things. If the tab page is visible it appears in the tab control and the user can select it, which brings it to the front. Also be aware that changing the visible property can change the order of the tab pages. This will cause problems if you refer to the pages by their index number in code.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to distinguish in the Selectionchanged event between the initialization and actual changing of tabs, check the previous index value, it will be -1 at initialization.